# After installation of fuse2 Ubuntu boot up stuck

Tags: boot, 22.04, fuse

Not entirely sure if these 2 things are related. But after installation of fuse 2 when I locked screen, I was not able to unlock it. On restart, the system is stuck in boot up mode.

I see black screen with details of service started.

I am on Ubuntu 22.04. Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Today I had the same trouble, when I installed **fuse2** before app using via appimage (it returned error and offered to install fuse2, what I did).

Next boot was failed with errors like:

> ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\CTDP], AE_NOT_FOUND...

To resolve it I executed some commands via **Recovery mode** (In grub choose "Advanced options for Ubuntu" then "Recovery Mode" at any kernel):

- choose "network" (enable networking at Recovery Menu). It automatically connects to your known network
- choose "root" (drop to root shell prompt)
- write commands:

```bash
apt remove --purge libfuse2
apt install fuse3 gnome-session gdm3
apt install --reinstall ubuntu-gnome-desktop
apt install --reinstall gnome-shell
```

And after that I could Log In successfully.

P.S. Ubuntu 23.04 with 6.4.11 kernel